# how to iterate in stream java 8 if a object have two or more different list?

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

this my model which in i want to set data.

```
public class StudentMarksModel {
    private String studentName;
    private Integer totalmarks;


    public StudentMarksModel(String studentName, Integer totalmarks) {
        super();
        this.studentName = studentName;
        this.totalmarks = totalmarks;
    }
// getter setter .....  

}
```

this is my entity

```
@Document(collection = "studentmarks")
    public class StudentMaksEntity {
        @Id
        private String id;
        @Field("studentid")
        private String studentid;

        @Field("studentname")
        private String studentname;

        @Field("subjectMarks")
        private List<SubjectMarks> subjectMarks;

       // getter setter

    }
```

list object inside entity

```
public class SubjectMarks {

@CreatedDate
@Field("created_date")
private Instant createdDate = Instant.now();
private String subject;
private Map<Integer,Integer> allmarks;
@Field("paperid")
private String paperId;

@Field("stnadard")
private Integer stnadard;
// getter setter
    }
```

This is how i done in my code

```
    List<StudentMaksEntity> list=studentMaksEntityRepository.findBySubjectMarksPaperId(paperId);
```

First i get name in some list

```
List<String> listofName= list.stream()
                                     .map(m->m.getStudentname())
                                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then i stream on marks and got sum of a subject marks

```
List<Integer> litsOfsumOfMarks=list.stream()
                                    .map(mp->mp.getSubjectMarks())
                    .flatMap(List::stream)
                    .map(mp->mp.getAllmarks().values().stream()
                                              .mapToInt(q->q.intValue()).sum())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<StudentMarksModel> studentMarksModel = Stream.iterate(0, s -> s + 1)
                .map(p -> new StudentMarksModel(listofName.get(p), litsOfsumOfMarks.get(p)))
                .limit(litsOfsumOfMarks.size()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

this is output of my code

```
[ {
  "studentName" : "S1",
  "totalmarks" : 5
}, {
  "studentName" : "S2",
  "totalmarks" : 5
}, {
  "studentName" : "S3",
  "totalmarks" : 5
}, {
  "studentName" : "S4",
  "totalmarks" : 5
} ]
```

in above code i have to use two different stream but i want to do it in one stream.

for example

```
list.stream().map(s -> s.getSubjectMarks())
                  .flatMap(List::stream)
                .map(p -> new StudentMarksModel("here i want name of student",p.getAllmarks().entrySet().stream().mapToInt(l -> l.getValue().intValue()).sum()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Show the StudentMarksEntity and the StudentMarksModel to better illustrate your description and help other people help you.

Comment: Your `litsOfsumOfMarks` is combining all the students subjects `s1 ->
 [sub1, sub2, sub3...], s2 ->
 [sub11, sub12...]` into one stream `(sub1->sub2->sub3->sub11->sub12...)`, then for each subject you sum all the marks for that subject, so now you are left with `(sub1mark->sub2mark->sub3mark->sub11mark->sub12mark...)`. How does this allow you to know which mark belongs to which student? Below that you do `litsOfsumOfMarks.get(p)`, but that mark you just got could belong to the wrong student! In any case, you should look into `Collectors#groupingBy`

Comment: @Aominè   thank you for response I have updated my post.

Comment: @smac89 thanks for response ... i upadted my post. it may clear now what iwanted to say.

Comment: @smac89 thanks for response ... i upadted my post. it may clear now what iwanted to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the methods you are using. For `listofName` it's:

```
stream -> map -> collect
```

for `litsOfsumOfMarks` it's:

```
stream -> map -> flatMap -> map -> collect
```

The method `map` will keep the number of elements, however `flatMap` doesn't have to. It means that the lists `listofName` and `litsOfsumOfMarks` may differ in size. If you are sure that the used `flatMap` will always return a stream of size 1, you can easily replace it with a `map`.

When you are sure both streams consist of the same number of elements, you can merge them for example using an auxiliary class `Pair`, so that you could do

```
list.stream()
    .map(el -> new Pair(<A>, <B>))
    // additional operations on either A, B or A & B
    .map(p -> new StudentMarksModel(p.getA(), p.getB()))
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this what you are looking for:

```
List<StudentMarksModel> studentMarksModels = list.stream()
                   .map(mp -> {
                        int sum = mp.getSubjectMarks()
                                    .stream()
                                    .flatMap((SubjectMarks t) -> 
                                             t.getAllmarks().values().stream())
                                    .mapToInt(q -> q.intValue()).sum();
                        return new StudentMarksModel(mp.getStudentname(), sum);
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thank you, but as per code standard curly braces inside map make it ugly. somewhere i read this coding standard.